# 'Join' Command Not Working - Need Assistance

Tags: discord.py

I saw many tutorials online to check my code, but none of them seems to help my problem. Here is my code for joining a voice channel:

```
@commands.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
```

I'm not making anything too fancy right now, I just want a way to get this to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code for joining a vc

```
channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
if ctx.voice_client is not None:
    return await ctx.voice_client.move_to(channel)
await channel.connect()
```

If the problem still persists, I need you to send more part of the code (Initialisation and Execution)